# Having trouble scheduling local notification to fire at specific time and date in swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I am trying to schedule a notification at a certain time in swift. My TimeString is a string that looks like 08:32 or 12:23. When I try to fire on this specific date and time, the notification only fires on the specific date however not the specific time. For instance if I change the year to 2016 it won't fire. If I change the month it won't fire. Yet regardless of what time I put in, if the date matches the current date, I am writing this on 1/28/2015, the notification fires regardless of time, In fact it fires as soon as I close the application as my code is in

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
}
```

My code does compile so I don't think there is an error in my code.

Is there any way to fire a notification at a specific time and not just a date in swift, and if so how do I implement this.

```
            var timeString : String =  "2015-01-28 " + TimeString;
            println(timeString);

            let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
            formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT");
            var date = formatter.dateFromString(timeString)



            var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
            localNotification.alertAction = "Block"
            localNotification.alertBody = block.description() + " Started";
            localNotification.fireDate = date
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

Comment: Can you print out the date variable after you set it and check that it is holding the time you expect?

Comment: I am a collaborator on this project and I can confirm that it was in fact holding the expected time

Comment: you forgot to set the desired timeZone for your localNotification before setting the fireDate

Comment: You have to check if the fireDate time is after or before the actual time, if the fireDate is after "now" you can set for the same day but if the fireDate is earlier then 'now' you have to set it for "tomorrow"

Comment: I think you should work with local time zone for your notification and date components

Comment: @pallavi Is the time in 24 hr format or 12 hr ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this approach to set your date:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let calendarComponents = NSDateComponents()
    calendarComponents.hour = 8   //you can get you time components 
    calendarComponents.second = 0 //from your string rather than 
    calendarComponents.minute = 0 //using fixed values
    calendarComponents.day = 28
    calendarComponents.year = 2015
    calendarComponents.month = 1
    let dateToFire = calendar.dateFromComponents(calendarComponents)
```

It worked for me. Hope this helps. :)